# React js createSelector reselect does not work. Issue connected with quality of renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

React js reselect does not work, while I use him in the slice. I have created big project smth like social media app, however when I wanted to check the quality of renders, I saw that the whole page is rendering for 6 or 7 times.

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldCxL.png)

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {createSelector} from "reselect";

export const optimizedEventsSlice = createSlice({
 name: 'optimizedEvents',
        initialState: {
           optimizedEvents: {
           next: null,
           previous: null,
           results: []
        }
},
 reducers: {
    initOptimizedEvents: (state, action) => {
        state.optimizedEvents = action.payload;
        },
   },
 });

 export const {
   initOptimizedEvents
 } = optimizedEventsSlice.actions;

 // export const getOptimizedEvents = (state) => state.optimizedEvents;

 export const getOptimizedEvents = createSelector(
   (state) => state.optimizedEvents,
   (optimizedEvents)=> optimizedEvents
 );

 export default optimizedEventsSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector you have written isn't doing anything useful at all.  Any selector that finishes with `x => x` as its "output selector" isn't actually *memoizing* anything.  Additionally, by returning the entire slice state, you are telling the UI layer that it should re-render any time `state.optimizedEvents` is updated in any way.

I'd recommend reading the Redux docs page on [Deriving Data with Selectors](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors) to better understand how Reselect works and how to use it correctly.